# Meteor keeps failing after update

Tags: meteor

I first get:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

Unable to resolve some modules:

  "./cancel.js" in /Users/abc123/Google Drive/Code/Meteor/canary/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js (os.osx.x86_64)

I20160830-00:34:12.965(-4)? ** You've set up some data subscriptions with Meteor.publish(), but
I20160830-00:34:13.022(-4)? ** you still have autopublish turned on. Because autopublish is still
I20160830-00:34:13.023(-4)? ** on, your Meteor.publish() calls won't have much effect. All data
I20160830-00:34:13.023(-4)? ** will still be sent to all clients.
I20160830-00:34:13.023(-4)? **
I20160830-00:34:13.023(-4)? ** Turn off autopublish by removing the autopublish package:
I20160830-00:34:13.024(-4)? **
I20160830-00:34:13.024(-4)? **   $ meteor remove autopublish
I20160830-00:34:13.024(-4)? **
I20160830-00:34:13.024(-4)? ** .. and make sure you have Meteor.publish() and Meteor.subscribe() calls
I20160830-00:34:13.025(-4)? ** for each collection that you want clients to see.
```

It Then gives a later error:

```
W20160830-00:34:25.614(-4)? (STDERR) /Users/abc123/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_1.6uhwa8++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20160830-00:34:25.615(-4)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160830-00:34:25.615(-4)? (STDERR)                        ^
W20160830-00:34:25.615(-4)? (STDERR) 
W20160830-00:34:25.616(-4)? (STDERR) Error: Cannot find module './cancel.js'
W20160830-00:34:25.616(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:85:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.616(-4)? (STDERR)     at module.exports (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:714:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.619(-4)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.bluebird.js.main.bluebird.js (node_modules/bluebird/js/main/bluebird.js:9:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.619(-4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.619(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.619(-4)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.stripe.lib.StripeResource.js (node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeResource.js:6:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.619(-4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.620(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.620(-4)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.stripe.lib.resources.Accounts.js (node_modules/stripe/lib/resources/Accounts.js:3:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.620(-4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.620(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.621(-4)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.stripe.lib.stripe.js (node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js:28:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.621(-4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.621(-4)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
W20160830-00:34:25.621(-4)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.server.stripe.js (server/stripe.js:1:10)
W20160830-00:34:25.621(-4)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
```

Anyone have any ideas of what to try or rule out?

meteor --version
Meteor 1.4.1.1

Comment: Try to remove `node_modules` and `npm install` again. Why did you place the app in Google Drive?

Comment: What is the Node version? `node --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the Stripe module I had in my imports was not updated and had caused the crash. Removing it solved the issue.